# JavaFX updating ListCell into FXML template, getting null pointer when accessing @FXML id

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I've got ListView. Tryn to modify Cells to display FXML template. For some reason when accessing @FXML Label setupName ( id of my label) inside ccontroller, I'm getting error that it's null: "Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.Label.setText(String)" because "this.setupName" is null"

Code:

```
public class setups implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Setup> setupsListView;
    @FXML
    private ListView<Tag> tagListView;
   private final int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
   public List<Tag> tags;
   public List<Setup> setups;


   public setups() throws IOException {
       this.tags =  new Tags().getTags();
       this.setups = new Setups().getSetups();

   }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        tagListView.getItems().addAll(tags);
        tagListView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        System.out.print("tag.id: ");
        System.out.println(tagListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().ID);
        setupsListView.getItems().addAll(setups);
        setupsListView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        System.out.print("setup.id: ");
        System.out.println(setupsListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getID());

        setupsListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Setup>, ListCell<Setup>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Setup> call(ListView<Setup> setupListView) {
                return new createSetupComponent();
            }
        });
    }

    public void clicked(){
        System.out.println(tagListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    }

    static class createSetupComponent extends ListCell<Setup>{
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Setup item, boolean empty){
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if(item != null){
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("setup-view.fxml"));
                loader.setController(new setup(item.getID(), item.getName()));
                try {
                    Parent parent = loader.load();
                    setGraphic(parent);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the controller:

```
package st.statistictraderv3.controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class setup {
    public int ID;
    public String name;

    @FXML
    private Label setupName;

    public setup(int i, String name){
        this.ID = i;
        this.name = name;
        setupName.setText(this.name);
        System.out.println("i of setup: " + i);
    }
}
```

If I comment out the "setupName.setText()", program is running ( however no dynamic labels which is what I'm aiming for )

Comment: just put setup has the controller in the setup-view.fxml and add a getter for the label

Comment: Do u want me to put this: fx:controller="st.statistictraderv3.controller.setups" in the setup-view.fxml? I can't do that, as FXML is invoked multiple times, and each time needs to have its own controller instance I think, or am I wrong?

Comment: Ok I've found the solution, so My setup.controller needs to Implement Initializable, and changes to Label gotta be apllied in initialized function :)